# Regex html url default

Tags: javascript, regex

How can I convert the format below into a normal url? For example, change this:

```
example.com\/1233612\/201307\/202111\/1039127998001_2534751409001_1193-1-h.mp4
```

into

```
example.com/1233612/201307/202111/1039127998001_2534751409001_1193-1-h.mp4
```

**EDIT:**

I have tried this but I still can't remove the `\` slash:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function encode() {
    var obj = document.getElementById('dencoder');
    var unencoded = obj.value;
    obj.value = encodeURIComponent(unencoded).replace(/'/g,"%27").replace(/"/g,"%22");  
}
function decode() {
    var obj = document.getElementById('dencoder');
    var encoded = obj.value;
    obj.value = decodeURIComponent(encoded.match('file=(.*?)($|&)')[1]);
    window.open(obj.value);
}
</script>
```

Comment: sorry..in javascripts

Comment: What have you tried? Have you any example code for us to work from? What were the errors you were getting?

Answer (score 0):

You need to double escape the backslashes.

```
var str = "example.com\/1233612\/201307\/202111\/1039127998001_2534751409001_1193-1-h.mp4"
str = str.replace('/\\\/',"")
```

The result of the above is:

```
example.com/1233612/201307/202111/1039127998001_2534751409001_1193-1-h.mp4
```

Comment: why this not work function decode() {
 var obj = document.getElementById('dencoder');
 var encoded = obj.value;
 
 var str = encoded.replace('/\\\/',"")
 alert(str);
}

Comment: do some debugging, what is the value of encoded? what is the value of obj? Make sure your data integrity is good.

Answer (score 0):

use a string replace. off the top of my head this should work (not tested).

```
var str = "example.com\/1233612\/201307\/202111\/1039127998001_2534751409001_1193-1-h.mp4";

str = str.replace('\/', '/');
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the following:

```
yourString.replace(/\\\//g, '/');
```